# How to stack rasters from a folder based on part of their name

Tags: stack, subset

I have a folder with hundreds rasters with different names. Some names are partially similar, except for the last 5 letters which characterize the year.  for example I have

```
"raster_a_2010.tif" 
"raster_a_1990.tif" 
"raster_f_2010.tif"
"raster_f_1990.tif"
```

I need to stack the rasters that share the first part of name, so (raster_a_2010 with raster_a_1990) but I need to do it automatically, without indicating one by one the pattern.

So far I did this but I'm still far from the solution: basically I'm trying to create a list of vectors that recognise each pattern and then I'd like to use this list to create the stack

```
raster_year <- base::list.files(file.path (dir_years,"raster")) 
#list of raster 
files_base <- basename(list.files(file.path (dir_years,"raster"))) 
files_group <- substring(files_base, 1, char(files_base) - 4) 
## Group the files by the extracted portion of the base name

files_grouped <- group_by(data.frame(file = raster_year , group = files_group)) files_grouped

V <-as.list(as.data.frame(files_grouped))
pattern <-  unique(V$group)

file_vector <- list.files(path = dir_years_raster, pattern =files_grouped$group, full.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `pattern` argument to `list.files`.

For example:

```
ff <- list.files(file.path(dir_years,"raster"), pattern="_a_")
```

Or if you first read all files you can subset them with grep

```
ff <- c("raster_a_2010.tif" , "raster_a_1990.tif", "raster_f_2010.tif", "raster_f_1990.tif")
grep("_a_", ff, value=TRUE)
#[1] "raster_a_2010.tif" "raster_a_1990.tif"
```

Comment: The problem is that I have hundreds of different patterns, so I was trying to create a list of vectors with the shared pattern e.g the final results of the code above is something like v<-c(_a_, _b_...).  then I need to Group these rasters based on the same pattern and create a stack

Comment: I show two ways to do what you ask for, that is, get the filenames that contain `_a_`  If that is not what you need then you should improve your question.